# PDF Info variables set inside the class

Tags: xetex, pdftex, hyperref, pdf

I have a simple custom class `mycustom.cls` defined as:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{mycustom}[2019/03/06 My custom class]
\LoadClass{article}
\RequirePackage{hyperxmp}
\RequirePackage[unicode]{hyperref}


\newcommand{\name}[2]{
    \def\@name{#1}
    \def\@surname{#2}
    \def\@fullname{#1 #2}
}

\newcommand{\address}[4]{
    \def\@neighborhood{#1}
    \def\@city{#2}
    \def\@state{#3}
    \def\@country{#4}
}
\endinput
```

And a minimal TeX file `mwe.tex`:

```
\documentclass{mycustom}

\name{John}{Smith}
\address{Spring Falls}{Helena-West Helena}{AR}{United States of America}

\makeatletter
\hypersetup{%
    pdftitle={\@fullname \cs{ } title},
    pdfsubject={\@neighborhood},
    pdfauthor={\@fullname},
    pdfcontactcity={\@city},
    pdfcontactcountry={\@country},
    pdfmetalang={en}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    foo bar barz
\end{document}
```

On that I have two questions:

1. Why the document compiles but returns a `Undefined control sequence. }` at line 14?
2. Is possible to move the `\hypersetup` to the class (with the variables), instead the main file?

Tried with PDFTeX and XeTeX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two undefined commands in your code:

1. `\phone`: add `\newcommand{\phone}[1]{\def\@phone{#1}}` in your class file.
2. `\cs{ }`: simply delete it in `pdftitle` or correct it to become a valid command (see point 1).

With the following MWE (package `filecontents` is only used in this MWE to have both tex code concatenated to one compilable MWE, you simply change your class file please):

```
\begin{filecontents*}{mycustom.cls}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{mycustom}[2019/03/06 My custom class]
\LoadClass{article}
\RequirePackage{hyperxmp}
\RequirePackage[unicode]{hyperref}


\newcommand{\name}[2]{
    \def\@name{#1}
    \def\@surname{#2}
    \def\@fullname{#1 #2}
}

\newcommand{\address}[4]{
    \def\@neighborhood{#1}
    \def\@city{#2}
    \def\@state{#3}
    \def\@country{#4}
}

\newcommand{\phone}[1]{\def\@phone{#1}} % <=============================
\endinput
\end{filecontents*}



\documentclass{mycustom}

\name{John}{Smith}
\phone{+1 123 555-1234}
\address{Spring Falls}{Helena-West Helena}{AR}{United States of America}

\makeatletter
\hypersetup{%
%   pdftitle={\@fullname \cs{ } title}, % <=============================
    pdftitle={\@fullname  title}, % <===================================
    pdfsubject={\@neighborhood},
    pdfauthor={\@fullname},
    pdfcontactcity={\@city},
    pdfcontactcountry={\@country},
    pdfmetalang={en}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    foo bar barz
\end{document}
```

you get no errors and the result:

[image: resulting pdf]

To move the complete command `\hypersetup` into the class file you can use command `\AtBeginDocument{...}`. That makes sure that all `\@name` etc. commands are defined when `\hypersetup` is called:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{mycustom.cls}
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/478520/pdf-info-variables-set-inside-the-class
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{mycustom}[2019/03/06 My custom class]
\LoadClass{article}
\RequirePackage{hyperxmp}
\RequirePackage[unicode]{hyperref}


\newcommand{\name}[2]{%
  \def\@name{#1}%
  \def\@surname{#2}%
}

\def\@fullname{\@name\ \@surname}

\newcommand{\address}[4]{%
  \def\@neighborhood{#1}%
  \def\@city{#2}%
  \def\@state{#3}%
  \def\@country{#4}%
}

\newcommand{\phone}[1]{\def\@phone{#1}}


\AtBeginDocument{% <====================================================
  \hypersetup{%
    pdftitle={\@fullname\ title}, 
    pdfsubject={\@neighborhood},
    pdfauthor={\@fullname},
    pdfcontactcity={\@city},
    pdfcontactcountry={\@country},
    pdfmetalang={en}
  }
} % <===================================================================
\endinput
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass{mycustom}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\name{John}{Smith}
\phone{+1 123 555-1234}
\address{Spring Falls}{Helena-West Helena}{AR}{United States of America}


\begin{document}
    foo bar barz \makeatletter\@fullname\makeatother
\end{document}
```

Comment: Right, phone there was left behind, I didn't noticed. We can safely remove all phone references and the problem that I point out is still there, that is:  Not adding `\cs{ }` leads to a PDF Info without spaces, the title will become: `Johh Smithtitle` but is expected `John Smith title`. That do not occurs without the `\cs`. Adding the `\cs{ }` leads to the correct pdf info, but returns the undefined control sequence error.

Comment: I will remove the `phone` references from OP since is very misleading. That unfortunately will lead to your first item "outdated". My apologies.

Comment: Nice to know about the `filecontents` environment.

Comment: Somehow the `backslash` do not showup in markup here. Indeed it works.

Comment: Even with the valid `\hypersetup` clause, moving it to the class file do not work.

Comment: No problem. I will not go anywhere.